# Rails Active Record .pluck not working with polymorphic model using geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

**The following line of code throws an error and I don't understand why.**

```
fav_arr.push(Address.near([@address.latitude, @address.longitude], 5).where(addressable_type: 'User').pluck(:addressable_id))
```

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column
>   "distance" does not exist

As soon as I add the .pluck(:addressable_id), it throws the error that the distance column does not exist.

**This one works tho:**

```
Address.near([@address.latitude, @address.longitude], 5).where(addressable_type: 'User').map{ |add|  fav_arr << add.addressable_id }
```

This is the SQL query

```
Address.near([@address.latitude, @address.longitude], 5).where(addressable_type: 'User').to_sql :

: SELECT "addresses"."addressable_id" FROM "addresses" WHERE (addresses.latitude BETWEEN 45.42903640844458 AND 45.57376819155542 AND addresses.longitude BETWEEN -73.68277080563716 AND -73.47627419436283 AND (3958.755864232 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((45.5014023 - addresses.latitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2) + COS(45.5014023 * PI() / 180) * COS(addresses.latitude * PI() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-73.5795225 - addresses.longitude) * PI() / 180 / 2), 2)))) BETWEEN 0.0 AND 5) AND "addresses"."addressable_type" = $1 ORDER BY distance ASC
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you tell us what the error is? :D Also - can you try `to_sql` on all the relevant things to show us what it's trying to translate them to?

Comment: @TarynEast just updated my answer, am I using .pluck incorreclty?

Comment: are you using any search gem like solarsearch or elastic search or geocorder?

Comment: @Manishh using geocoder yes.

Comment: try adding `order: false` to the near method e.g. `Address.near([@address.latitude, @address.longitude], 5, order: false)`. The problem is `pluck` overrides the select statement which would naturally contain the `distance` alias (which is then converted to a virtual attribute of your model). Since this alias does not exist in the query it cannot order by it thus the error.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this

```
Address.near([@address.latitude, @address.longitude], 5).where(addressable_type: 'User').reorder('').pluck(:addressable_id)
```

Extending @engineersmnky comment, near and pluck both modifies the select statement.